# Clicking on a PromptDialog.Choice from a previous prompt

Tags: c#, botframework

Is it possible for the user to click the button of a previous prompt and be redirected back to that state?

---

For example:

> Bot: Here are your options: Menu, Promotions, Directions (given in the
>   form of a PromptDialog.Choice)
>
> User: *clicks on menu*
>
> Bot: Starters, Mains, Desserts (given in the form of a
>   PromptDialog.Choice)
>
> User: *clicks on Mains*
>
> Bot: Here are the mains: (list of mains, followed by a
>   PromptDialog.Choice leading somewhere else)
>
> User: *scrolls up, clicks on Promotions*
>
> ***Alternatively***,
>
> User: *scrolls up, clicks on Starters*

---

I know I can handle dialog switching through scorables, but what if I have a dialog that has 4-5 prompts and the user scrolls up to tap on one of the earlier prompts within the same dialog? Is there a mechanism to handle it?

I'm running Bot Framework on C# if that helps

Comment: Bot records the state of the on-going conversation. So most of the time it expects certain kind of input at certain stage of the conversation. For example when a button prompt was triggered, then bot expects that a button from the prompt will be clicked. And some times bot expects that user clicked something. If user scrolls up on the chat history and clicks a buttons, the bot response will be based on what bot expects at this stage. In your case, the click of the button will send a text message, and if bot expected that kind of message, if will take appropriate action.

Answer (score 1):

The solution to this that most people use to have reponse validations so that if a user responds to a previous prompt the code can either say something like "not a valid response", or the code can restart from that prompt point depending on what you want to accomplish.  This is a good place to take advantage of state data.

If you prompt choices are the same for all your prompts (such as yes/no) this is going to be very difficult and may not be able to be accomplished.  If you have unique values for your prompts you can store "steps" in `ConversationData`, check the user input for which step it belongs to and set the step count to the step that they responded to.

Some rough pseudocode would look something like this:

`context.ConversationData.SetValue("step", 1);`
user answers step 1
check that the input is appropriate for the step
perform logic on the user input

`context.ConversationData.SetValue("step", 2);`
user answers step 2
check that the input is appropriate for the step
perform logic on user input

`context.ConversationData.SetValue("step", 3);`
user scrolls up and answers step 1
check that the input is appropriate for the step  (in this case it isn't)
reset the step count to 1
perform logic on user input for that step

Then from there you decide whether to continue in order of your steps, or you could have other state variables that would track what step they were on before that like `context.ConversationData.SetValue("step3", true);` meaning the user already answered for step 3 and the next prompt would be step 4.